# Javascript: Adding 0 values to arrays of different sizes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, highcharts, underscore.js

Quite complicated to explain so I will try to be explicit.

I have an object, data, which is an array of objects that includes an array of objects and a string:

```
var groups = [
    { 
        bars: [
            {label: 'a', value: 28},
            {label: 'c', value: 16}
        ],
        string: 'one'
    },
    {
        bars: [
            {label: 'a', value: 3},
            {label: 'b', value: 17},
            {label: 'c', value: 24}
        ],
        string: 'two'
    },
    {
        bars: [
            {label: 'a', value: 12},
            {label: 'd', value: 7},
            {label: 'e', value: 36}
        ],
        string: 'three'
    },
    {
        bars: [
            {label: 'c', value: 32},
            {label: 'e', value: 2}
        ],
        string: 'four'
    }
]
```

I need all "bars" objects to be the same size and have a 0 value if the object for said label does not exist. As you can see, the label key associated with "bars" is a finite list. My main problem here is that the size of the "groups" object as well as the size of the "bars" object is dynamic. With underscore, I have used:

```
var labelNames = _.uniq(_.flatten
    (_.map(data.groups,function(groups) {
    return _.pluck(groups.bars, 'label');
})));
```

to extract the list of known labels giving me

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I now want to map this array to the bars object giving me this output:

```
var groups = [
    { 
        bars: [
            {label: 'a', value: 28},
            {label: 'b', value: 0},
            {label: 'c', value: 16},
            {label: 'd', value: 0},
            {label: 'e', value: 0}
        ],
        string: 'one'
    },
    {
        bars: [
            {label: 'a', value: 3},
            {label: 'b', value: 17},
            {label: 'c', value: 24},
            {label: 'd', value: 0},
            {label: 'e', value: 0}
        ],
        string: 'two'
    },
    {
        bars: [
            {label: 'a', value: 12},
            {label: 'b', value: 0},
            {label: 'c', value: 0},
            {label: 'd', value: 7},
            {label: 'e', value: 36}
        ],
        string: 'three'
    },
    {
        bars: [
            {label: 'a', value: 0},
            {label: 'b', value: 0},
            {label: 'c', value: 32},
            {label: 'd', value: 0},
            {label: 'e', value: 2}
        ],
        string: 'four'
    }
]
```

If helpful, I must have even bars because I have created a highcharts series with these objects [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/).
I hope that makes sense. Any help would be appreciated. I've been going crazy trying to figure this out.

Comment: Loop through each element of `groups` with `_.each`. Use `_.pluck` to get all the labels of `bars`, and `_.difference` between that and the known labels to get the missing ones. Then add elements with those labels and `value: 0`.

Comment: Thank you! This got me most of the way there, so I am posting it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I went with for those who stumble on this.

```
_.each(data.groups, function(group) {
    var currentValues = _.pluck(group.bars, 'label');
    var zeroValues = _.difference(labelNames, currentValues);
    _.each(zeroValues, function(newLabel) {
        group.bars.push({label: newLabel, value: 0});
    });
});
```

Comment: Very nice, really demonstrates the power of underscore.js.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
// First, iterate over each group
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {

    var bars = groups[i].bars;

    // Second, iterate over each of the previously collected labels, e.g. var labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    for (var j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {

        // Assume label does not exist, until proven otherwise
        var labelDoesNotExist = true;

        // Third, iterate over the bars' existing labels
        for (var k = 0; k < bars.length; k++) {

            var label = bars[k].label;

            // Check if the label matches the current iteration of pre-collected labels
            if (label == labels[j]) {
                labelDoesNotExist = false;
            }
        }

        // If no existing label matches any of the pre-collected labels, then create a new label with value of 0
        if (labelDoesNotExist) {
            bars.push({
                'label': labels[j],
                'value': '0'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***A functional and EcmaScript6 alternative:***

First, get labels: ['a', 'b, 'c', ...]

```
let labels = groups
  .reduce((res, item) => 
    [...res, ...item.bars.map(b => b.label)], 
  [])
  .filter((value, index, self) => 
    self.indexOf(value) === index
  )
  .sort()
```

> Saving the day with reduce and concat!

And second step, make job without vendor libraries:

```
let newgroups = groups.map(item  => 
  Object.assign({}, item, {bars : [
    ...item.bars, 
    ...labels.filter(l => 
        !item.bars.some(b => b.label == l)
      )
      .map(l => ({label:l, value:0}))
  ].sort((a, b) => a.label < b.label ? -1:1)})
);
```

> The final `sort` is opcional, but bars itens can be better with this.

Works on Chrome and actual engines without transpile.
**ES6 is life**

Comment: A more readable alternative https://gist.github.com/AbraaoAlves/e1ed0cc21eca5750fa80610e3674bd05